# BUG? RangeSelector Buttons not working correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I think I have found a bug in the newest version of Highstock:

Following RangeSelector is defined:

```
 rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{ type: 'day', count: 1, text: '1d' },
                               { type: 'day', count: 7, text: '7d' },
                               { type: 'month', count: 1, text: '1m' },
                               { type: 'month', count: 3, text: '3m' },
                               { type: 'year', count: 1, text: '1y' },
                               { type: 'all', text: 'All' }],
                selected: 6, // all
                inputEnabled: false
            }
```

Now I am displaying exactly 1 year of data. That means when I press on "1y" and on "all" the exact same view is displayed. Also both buttons are active when I press on "all":

[image]

So far so good. Now I am selecting a different range again (let's say "1d"). The data gets correctly displayed. However now comes the **bug**: the range selector still has "1y" selected, which results in this:

[image]

This is an invalid state and I supposte it's a bug. Is there some sort of a workaround I could use?

I am using Highstock v1.3.9

EDIT: Fiddle to reproduce this error:
http://jsfiddle.net/xdRk8/5/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run Fiddle
2. Click on "All" in the range selector
3. Click on "1d" in Range selector

Comment: Please reproduce live demo, as jsFiddle.

Comment: @SebastianBochan added fiddle to question

Comment: I reproduced your example as simpler example http://jsfiddle.net/28LNP/1/ and it is default behaviour, becasue you have selected all option. In case when you disable it, then buttons work as single button, not related with 1Y.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yes but still this clearly results in an invalid state and causes confusion when viewing data. If you tell me this is default behaviour then you haven't thought this through.

Comment: You can disable ALL button from rangeselector  http://jsfiddle.net/xdRk8/6/

Comment: @SebastianBochan okay, I can do that as a work around when the user picks exactly 1 year to display. However this is quite an ugly approach in my opinion. Will this get fixed at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using a work-around. I check the time delta of the data to display if it is exactly one year. If no I add the button "All" dynamically to the options before I create the highstock chart:

```
// Workaround to fix a bug in Highstock 1.3.9 where
// the "1y" button was active all the time when exactly
// 1 year of data is displayed
var past = new Date(plotEnd.getTime());
past.setYear(past.getFullYear() - 1);
if (past.getTime() == plotStart.getTime()) {
    var oneYear = true;
}

var chartOptions = {
    // ...
}

if (!oneYear) {
    chartOptions.rangeSelector.buttons.push({ type: 'all', text: 'All' });
}
```